# will playframework version 1 become obsolete?

Tags: playframework

Now that playframework has a new version 2 that is completely different from version 1; what will happen to the latter? should all projects written in play 1 be migrated to version 2 absolutely? I wonder if one could rely on play 1 not becoming obsolete and unsupported in the near or medium future?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the key statements that has been given from the core development team, is that they themselves have many apps written in Play 1.x, and therefore, they will continue to support Play 1.x. Play has been around for quite a while now, and even before it was public, it was being used by Zenexity as the framework for building their client's web apps.

They are not looking to go back and re-engineer the Play 1.x web apps, and in many ways, the support and community around 1.x is stronger than 2. If you are looking to start to use more real-time features, then maybe you should move to Play 2, but if you are happy with what Play 1 offers...why move?
Nicolas Leroux and some of the other core developers have committed to maintaining the Play 1 project, and since Play 2 was released, 1.2.5 has been rolled out, and 1.3 is on its way.

That said, if you do decide to migrate, I would highly recommend using the Groovy template engine for 2.x as it may make the migration process easier.

Personally, I prefer 1.x to 2.x, but that is a pure matter of taste. I invested a lot of time into 1.x, and know it well, and the 2.x features are not enough to pull me away from the ease and beauty of Play 1.

Comment: We reverted from play 2.x to 1.2.5 because 2.x was just way toooooo slow right now.  we love the real-time development nature of play.

Comment: +1 I like play v1, and spent long time learning play 2.. and very-time have some issue. I like scala, but I can not say that I like play2 (because it is low, still has issue with top ides). Maybe in 1 year I will check out v2 again.

Answer (score 2):

in the near future, it might be better to stick with play 1.+ - since there are a number of modules that work with 1.+ - it may take some more time for 2.+ to become stable and with even greater module support (hence migrating your play 1.+ project to 2.+ at this point might not be the best thing to do).  Using play 2.+ after a few minor releases might make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no need to rewrite your existing code at least for existing, stable apps. The main goal for each application *should be* to be independent from initial version of the soft that was built with. `Play 1.x` will be under team's maintenance for some time, but as it was told many times - there will be no new features added to it, as current main direction of development is 2.x+

Of course if your app is in initial phase of development and/or you suppose many changes in the future, maybe 'jumping' to newer version will be better idea right now. Later you'll need to migrate much more stuff.

On the other hand, I would definitely recommend to start new project with version 2.x, staying at 1.x level will cause that you'll wake some day with application built on unsupported version.

About modules availability: keep in mind that modules are created by the community. I wouldn't condition my choice on modules availability between Play's versions 1 and 2, as it just a pieces of code, and many of them can be just written again in short time. Finally as Play's is development framework - the modules are just nice shortcuts, **not** the `absolutely required base` for any new application.

Comment: ok. There will be need to maintain code after some time anyway. and in this phase migrating to 2.x will make more sense. Thanks